# IllegalStateException while adding bitmap to Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, illegalstateexception

I was trying to set a bitmap image to a canvas using    `setBitMap` ,at that time I got an IllegalStateException.This canvas have some images on it currently, I am trying to replace it.
 Any one have any idea why this happened?

**Code Snippet**

```
editBm = Bitmap.createBitmap(951, 552, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    
        Canvas mCanvas=new Canvas(editBm);
        eBit=LoadBMPsdcard(filePath); ---->returns a bitmap when the file path to the file is provided
        Log.i("BM size", editBm.getWidth()+"");
        mCanvas.setBitmap(eBit);
```

I am not getting any NullPointer errors and the method  `LoadBMPsdcard()`  is working good.

Please let me know about any ideas you have ...

Thanks in advance

Happy Coding

Comment: post your logcat and LoadBMPsdcard() method

Answer (score 6):

IllegalStateException could be thrown because you're loading a Bitmap (eBit) and use `mCanvas.setBitmap(eBit)`  without checking if the bitmap is mutable. This is requiered to draw on the Bitmap. To make sure your Bitmap is mutable use:

```
eBit=LoadBMPsdcard(filePath);
Bitmap bitmap = eBit.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) instead of the setBitmap. It looks like you've already set a bitmap to draw into by passing it to the canvas constructor, so now you just need to draw everything onto it.

Answer (score 1):

`Canvas.setBitmap()` throws `IllegalStateException` if and only if `Bitmap.isMutable()` returns true.  `Bitmap.createBitmap()` builds an immutable Bitmap instance only, in all of its forms.  To create a mutable bitmap you either use `new Bitmap()`, or `Bitmap.copy(true)`, depending on whether you have a source bitmap that you want to start with.  A typical block for me looks like:

```
Bitmap image = ...
Canvas c = new Canvas(image.isMutable()?image:image.copy(true));
...
```

This assumes, of course, that you don't mind clobbering the source Bitmap (which I generally don't but that's by no means universal).